# Hashset contain/equal on value basis

Tags: java, hashset

Can I check if an object with the same **values** already exists in a hashset?

e.g.

```
int[] a = {1,2,3};
int[] b = {1,2,3};

Set<int[]> appeared = new HashSet<int[]>();

appeared.add(a);
appeared.contains(b);
```

appeared.contains(b) will return false since a and b are not the same objects but I would like a function which returns true in this case.
In my function I got a hashset which stores a complex class and directly comparing every primitive datatype in every array is a little bit too much.
Is there anything like hashvalues I can use or any neat trick I don't know yet? Thanks for your help.

Comment: You cannot use arrays as keys "directly" in Sets or Maps. You must use a wrapper type.

Comment: If I create a wrapper class do I have to implement equals and hashCode manually? If so is there any best practice how to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This prints `true`.

```
Integer[] a = {1,2,3};
Integer[] b = {1,2,3};

Set<List<Integer>> appeared = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();

appeared.add(Arrays.asList(a));
System.out.println(appeared.contains(Arrays.asList(b)));
```